# git merge subdirectory with another repository

Tags: git, git-merge

I have a git repository (named X) where I develop a larger project. Now I want to use code from another git repository (named Y) and include it in my repo X under X/A/B.

I want to make changes to X/A/B and commit it to my own repository (X). That would simply be possible by copying the code from repo Y to X/A/B. But I also want to merge changes from Y to X/A/B. How could I do that?

Comment: [gitmodule](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitmodules.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I achieved the desired result with git subtree. I can commit the changes of X/A/B to the repository X, but also pull from Y.

This [blog entry](http://blog.nwcadence.com/git-subtrees/) explains the steps very quick.